# Error: Signature verification failed with PDA when transferring SPL token

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account, anchor-spl

I have been figuring this one out for a few days. Appreciate the help.

I want to be able to send the tokens from the PDA ATA to the user who is removing his vault.\

This is the error I am getting: `Error: Signature verification failed`

My function:

```
   pub fn remove_vault(
    ctx: Context<RemoveVault>,
    _vault_idx: u8,
    // _info_address: Pubkey,
) -> Result<()> {
    // Decreate total todo count
    let user_profile = &mut ctx.accounts.user_profile;
    user_profile.vault_count = user_profile.vault_count.checked_sub(1).unwrap();

    let vault_account = &mut ctx.accounts.vault_account;

    let time_diff = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp - vault_account.staked_at;

    let vault_info = &mut ctx.accounts.vault_info;

    msg!("Total staking time (seconds): {}", time_diff.to_string());
    // msg!("Token program: {}", vault_info.token);
    msg!("CMV2 ID: {}", vault_info.cmv2);

    // let seed = &[&[INFO_TAG]];

    // let sender = &mut ctx.accounts.vault_info.key();

    // let sender_key = sender.as_ref();

    let inner = vec![INFO_TAG.as_ref()];
    // &[&["INFO_STATE".as_ref(),ctx.accounts.authority.key().as_ref()]]
    let outer = vec![inner.as_slice()];

    // let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
    //     ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
    //     token::Transfer {
    //         from: ctx.accounts.sender.to_account_info(),
    //         to: ctx.accounts.receiver.to_account_info(),
    //         authority: ctx.accounts.vault_info.to_account_info(),
    //     },
    //     // &[&[INFO_TAG]],
    // outer.as_slice(),
    // );

    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info().clone(),
        to: ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info().clone(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info().clone(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.clone();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        cpi_program,
        cpi_accounts,
        outer.as_slice(), // outer.as_slice()
    );

    token::transfer(cpi_ctx, 10 * 10 * 9)?;

    // token::transfer(cpi_ctx, 1)?;

    // No need to decrease last todo idx

    // Todo PDA already closed in context

    Ok(())
```

My Struct:

```
pub struct RemoveVault<'info> {
#[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [USER_TAG, authority.key().as_ref()],
    bump,
    has_one = authority,
)]
pub user_profile: Box<Account<'info, UserProfile>>,

#[account(
    mut,
    close = authority,
    seeds = [VAULT_TAG, authority.key().as_ref(), &[vault_idx].as_ref()],
    bump,
    has_one = authority,
)]
pub vault_account: Box<Account<'info, UserVault>>,

#[account(mut, signer,
    seeds = [INFO_TAG
    // , authority.key().as_ref()
    ],
    bump,
)]
pub vault_info: Box<Account<'info, VaultInfo>>,

#[account(mut)]
/// CHECK: PDA is handling this as signer
pub authority: Signer<'info>,

pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

#[account(mut, has_one = owner)]
/// CHECK: PDA is handling this as signer
from: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
// #[account(mut)]
#[account(mut, "from.mint == to.mint")]
/// CHECK: PDA is handling this as signer
to: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
#[account(mut)]
/// CHECK: PDA is handling this as signer
owner: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
/// CHECK: PDA is handling this as signer
token_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

}

My testing script:

```
it("User Vault removed!", async () => {
// Add your test here.
// const tx = await program.methods.initializeUser().rpc();

console.log("user:", user.publicKey)
console.log("program:", program.programId)
console.log("token program:", TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)

console.log("Mint:", mintPubkey.toBase58())


const [userProfilePDA] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([
  utf8.encode("USER_STATE"),
  user.publicKey.toBuffer(),
],
  program.programId
);
console.log("userProfilePDA", userProfilePDA.toBase58());

const userProfile = await program.account.userProfile.fetch(userProfilePDA);
// console.log("UserProfile:", userProfile)
console.log("Last vault:", userProfile.lastVault)

const [vaultAccountPDA] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([
  utf8.encode("VAULT_STATE"),
  user.publicKey.toBuffer(),
  new anchor.BN(0).toBuffer()
],
  program.programId
);
console.log("vaultAccountPDA:", vaultAccountPDA.toBase58());

const [vaultInfoPDA] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([
  utf8.encode("INFO_STATE"),
  // user.publicKey.toBuffer(),
],
  program.programId
);
console.log("vaultInfoPDA:", vaultInfoPDA.toBase58());


let tokenAccountPubkeyUser = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(program.provider.connection, user, mintPubkey, user.publicKey)


console.log("tokenProgram:", TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58())
console.log("receiver ATA:", tokenAccountPubkeyUser.address.toBase58())

let tokenAuth = await program.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(tokenAccountPubkeyUser.address);

console.log("receiver (user) ATA owner:", tokenAuth.owner.toBase58())

let tokenAccountPubkeyVault = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(program.provider.connection, user, mintPubkey, vaultInfoPDA, true)


console.log("sender (VaultInfo) ATA:", tokenAccountPubkeyVault.address.toBase58())


let txhash = await transferChecked(
  program.provider.connection, // connection
  user, // payer
  tokenAccountPubkeyUser.address, // from (should be a token account)
  mintPubkey, // mint
  tokenAccountPubkeyVault.address, // to (should be a token account)
  user, // from's owner
  10e9, // amount, if your deciamls is 9, send 10^9 for 1 token
  9 // decimals
);


let tokenAmount = await program.provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(tokenAccountPubkeyVault.address);

console.log("VaultInfo ATA supply:", tokenAmount.value.uiAmount)

tokenAuth = await program.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(tokenAccountPubkeyVault.address);

console.log("VaultATA owner:", tokenAuth.owner.toBase58())

tokenAuth = await program.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(program.programId);

console.log("Program owner:", tokenAuth.owner.toBase58())

tokenAuth = await program.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(vaultInfoPDA);

console.log("vaultInfoPDA owner:", tokenAuth.owner.toBase58())



const tx = await program.rpc.removeVault(0, {
  accounts: {
    authority: user.publicKey,
    userProfile: userProfilePDA,
    vaultAccount: vaultAccountPDA,
    vaultInfo: vaultInfoPDA,
    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    from: tokenAccountPubkeyVault.address,
    to: tokenAccountPubkeyUser.address,
    owner: vaultInfoPDA,
    // sender: vaultInfoPDA
  },
  signers: []
})

console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your struct, `authority` is a signer:

```
#[account(mut)]
/// CHECK: PDA is handling this as signer
pub authority: Signer<'info>,
```

But you're not passing in `user` as a signer, so try to add `user` as a signer. Note the last parameter:

```
const tx = await program.rpc.removeVault(0, {
  accounts: {
    authority: user.publicKey,
    userProfile: userProfilePDA,
    vaultAccount: vaultAccountPDA,
    vaultInfo: vaultInfoPDA,
    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    from: tokenAccountPubkeyVault.address,
    to: tokenAccountPubkeyUser.address,
    owner: vaultInfoPDA,
    // sender: vaultInfoPDA
  },
  signers: [user]
})
```